# Installing python package linear models using the .tar.gz file

Tags: python, installation, pip, linearmodels

I'm trying to install linearmodels with this file (linearmodels-4.20.tar.gz) because of company VPN blocking the simpler `pip install linearmodels`.

I tried with seaborn the command below from the anaconda prompt and it worked.
`pip install C:/Users/...../seaborn-0.11.2.tar.gz`.

I tried the same for linearmodel but it appears "Installing build dependencies" that fails (maybe for company VPN?). I already tried with --no-deps: `pip install --no-deps C:/Users/...../linearmodels-4.25.tar.gz` but nothing changes.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Environment

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.3

Comment: you need to install the dependencies of this package. if regular pip install is not possible you need to install those dependencies manually as you did with seaborn

Comment: Are Python 3.7+, NumPy (1.15+), SciPy (1.3+), pandas (0.25+), statsmodels (0.11+), xarray (0.13+, optional), Cython (0.29.21+, optional) the dependencies? I already have them installed (with at least the minimum required version) except for xarray and Cython.
https://pypi.org/project/linearmodels/#description

Comment: `print(np.__version__)
print(sp.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)
print(sm.__version__)`
1.18.5
1.5.0
1.0.5
0.11.1

Comment: Take a look at the [requirements file here](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/blob/main/requirements.txt). It shows what you need to have to run `linearmodels`. Looks like you also need `property_cached>=1.6.3`, `mypy_extensions>=0.4`, `pyhdfe>=0.1`, and `formulaic`, at least to run the latest version. You might get more help by posting your install log as a GitHub issue for `linearmodels`.